# Removing Flutter accessibility description from decorative image

Tags: flutter

I have used a decorative image in my Flutter image using the `Image` class.

When I use Android Talkback to hover over the image it says "unlabelled image", is there a way to remove this description so nothing is announced?

The [Android docs](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7158690) have guidance on removing it for Android, how should I do this in Flutter?

> Decorative images or images that don't convey meaningful information
>   graphically do not require content labels. In these cases, set an
>   android:contentDescription attribute of "@null" or an
>   android:importantForAccessibility attribute of "no".